# NSURLConnection Response cut some parts

Tags: php, objective-c

I have an NSURLConection, all works perfectly :)
I get a VALUE from a php script which looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "372";
?>
```

So it returns 372.

But my Problem is now, that it returns some other stuff I dont want, I only want this number. when I load the php file in my webbrowser it only gives me 372 but with an NSURLConnection I get this:

[image: NSURLConnectionResponse]

I only want to get 372 only, not the stuff underneath, is there a way to only get the number by formatting the responses(NSString).

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {


        [progressAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];


    if (connection == connectionUpload) {
        [self newConnection];
        connectionUpload = nil;
    }
    else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Response" message:response delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        connectionImage = nil;
    }
}

-(void)newConnection {

    NSURLRequest *requestID = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jackdev.comeze.com/upload/randomnumber.php"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    connectionImage = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestID delegate:self];

    if (connectionImage) {

        //connect


    } else {

        //error
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    if (connection == connectionImage) {

        response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    else {

        //nothing
    }
}
```

There are two connections. conectionUpload uploads the image and checks when it is done. if it is done, a new connection starts to get the Image ID. In my upload.php file I write the randomID of an image to randomnumber.php and the response of randomnumber.php will be loaded into a String.

Comment: Can you provide some of your code? such as the NSURLConnection and the UIAlertView

Comment: The content you dumped with iOS is actually the content returned by response (not visible in standard browser view of course). Obviously your hoster dynamically adds some JS "Analytics Code". Please describe your server setup to clarify things.

Comment: I added some code and shortly explained whats happening .) Matze: What do you mean by server setup? :) sorry.
GUYS: I disabled the analytics code. It was possible in my panel of the webjhoster. let me test if it works :) EDIT: WORKS :)